# Supervisord at 99% cpu usage

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, supervisord

I've installed `supervisord` using:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

on my Ubuntu 14.04 server as per the instructions in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration).

I've noticed that the `supervisorctl` process on my server is running constantly at extremely high usage (never below 80%, often at 99%).

The contents of my worker conf file are:

```
[program:interactions-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/interactions/current/artisan queue:listen sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubuntu
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/interactions/storage/worker.log
```

What could be causing the process to take up so many resources?

Comment: What do you see if you log timestamps at the entrance and exit of that PHP page? Do you see a bunch of requests? Are the requests taking a while to finish?

Comment: there's a typo in the worker.conf you pasted here: `--` and `sleep` should be together: `--sleep`

Comment: sourcejedi, that was a typo caused by my paste. Fixed. Paul, requests are not taking considerable time to execute - it's simply sending e-mails, and those are being delivered as expected within a few seconds of the task being fired.

Comment: Attaching `strace` to `supervised` could give you a rough clue what `supervised` is doing all along.  My first guess would also be that it is constantly respawning the supervised process.

Answer (score 3):

The `autorestart` directive

> specifies if supervisord should automatically restart a process if it
>   exits when it is in the RUNNING state.

(Source: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)

In other words, once the PHP page is processed...the interpreter exits...and the whole thing restarts again...and again...etc. Is that to be expected?

Comment: E.g. run `supervisorctl` a couple of times and see if the PID is changing all the time.  Kind of a flaw not to rate-limit it, in case there's an error.

Comment: The process id is constantly the same

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question posted, so feel it doesn't warrant the bounty. My rep is too low on unix.stackexchange to downvote.

Comment: @Amo I think that Paul is suggesting that the high CPU usage is because `supervisord` is constantly respawning itself. If that is indeed what is happening, then huge CPU usage is to be expected. Paul, if I'm right, please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: The the pid is the same, Supervisor can not be re-spawning itself as I assume that would generate a new process.

Comment: What about the PID of the app it's supervising?

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of supervisord?
Old supervisord seems to have high CPU occupation issues.

And regarding the laravel queue worker, use queue:work --daemon to reduce the CPU impact, according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#daemon-queue-listener

> The queue:work Artisan command includes a --daemon option for forcing the queue worker to continue processing jobs without ever re-booting the framework. This results in a significant reduction of CPU usage when compared to the queue:listen command: